# c# winforms - changing value of array doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

In form1 class I have:

```
public Color Btn1Color
{
  get { return btn1.BackColor; }
  set { btn1.BackColor = value; }
}
```

In the Model class I have:

```
private Color[,] clr = new Color[50, 50];
clr[0, 0] = form1.btn1Color;
clr[0, 0] = Color.Aqua; //the color of my button does not visually change.
//But if i instead use this line it does visually change:
//form1.btn1Color = Color.Aqua;
```

Why doesn't the first way (just setting the array element) work? Is there a C# limitation of setting form properties from an array?

Comment: `Is there a C# limitation of setting form properties from an array?` - TBH, this wouldn't be my first guess...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Color` is a structure in C#, which is copied during assignments.  That means when you assign:

```
clr[0,0] = form1.btn1Color;
```

It assigns a copy of the value of `form1.btn1Color` to `clr[0,0]`.  Thus, when you then say:

```
clr[0,0] = Color.Aqua;
```

You are overwriting the copy, not the original.

In fact, even if `Color` were a `class` instead of `struct` the result would be the same, because in that case you'd overwrite the reference.

If you wanted assigning the array to modify the original object, you would need to wrap the object in the array to refer back to the original object that has the member holding the `Color`, since `Color` is an immutable `struct`.

**Update**: based on your follow up question, one thing you *could* do (there are really many ways to do this) is to wrap the `Color` in a wrapper class, and use that wrapper for the array and as the member in `form1` as well:

```
    public class ColorHolder
    {
        // construct ColorHolder from Color
        public ColorHolder(Color color)
        {
            Current = color;
        }

        // can assign ColorHolder to Color with implicit conversion
        public static implicit operator Color(ColorHolder value)
        {
            return value.Current;
        }

        // get or set current color
        public Color Current { get; set; }
    }
```

Then, change `form1.btn1Color` to be `ColorHelper` instead of `Color` and this works:

```
        ColorHolder[,] clr = new ColorHolder[50, 50];

        // sets current color of btn1Color to black.
        form1.btn1Color = new ColorHolder(Color.Black);

        // assign array location to the color holder
        clr[0, 0] = form1.btn1Color;

        // this changes the current color of form1's btn1Color
        clr[0, 0].Current = Color.Aqua;
```

**Note**: You *could* also allow a conversion from `Color` -> `ColorHolder` as well, but this could lead to hard-to-track bugs as it would allow:

```
        clr[0,0] = Color.Aqua;
```

Which would assign a *new* `ColorHolder` instead of changing the existing using `Current`.  Thus I'd avoid the `Color` -> `ColorHolder` conversion and stick with something like the above.

You could even generalize this `Holder` code to support any type, like:

```
    public class Holder<T>
    {
        public Holder(T value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        public static implicit operator T(Holder<T> holder)
        {
            return holder.Value;
        }

        public T Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Then instead of `ColorHolder` you'd have `Holder<Color>` or any other type.  Again, this would be used like the following (assuming `form1`'s `btn1Color` member is now `Holder<Color>`):

```
        Holder<Color>[,] clr = new Holder<Color>[50, 50];

        form1.btn1Color = new Holder<Color>(Color.Black);

        clr[0, 0] = form1.btn1Color;

        // sets the Color in form1.btn1Color to Aqua...
        clr[0, 0].Value = Color.Aqua;
```

Comment: How can I get it to overwrite the original? My idea was to store the button names in an array so that my array dimensions would match to the relevant button in a 50x50 block of buttons.

Comment: There's several ways it could be done, but you'd have to rethink your array.  You could have the array be an array of the button itself, the problem is you want it to store the Color, which is a `struct` which is immutable and copy-by-value.  So storing the `Color` itself won't do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

`clr[0,0] = form1.btn1Color;` assigns the current *value* of the button's colour to the array.

Once this is done there is no relationship between the button's Color property and the array. It's the *value* of the colour that's put into the array, not the reference to the button's background colour.

If you really want to set button colours through an array in this way, store an array of buttons and reference the BackColor property when you set the colour.

Comment: How can I get it to overwrite the original? My idea was to store the button names in an array so that my array dimensions would match to the relevant button in a 50x50 block of buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you wanted to do instead was to

```
clr[0, 0] = Color.Aqua;
form1.btn1Color = clr[0, 0] ;
```

Comment: How can I get it to overwrite the original? My idea was to store the button names in an array so that my array dimensions would match to the relevant button in a 50x50 block of buttons. ie btn17_48.

Comment: Do you mean you want to store key value pairs  with keys as button name and value as color? You may use hashtable instead of an array.

Answer (score 1):

Properties and Variables are assigned from right to left. To assign a value to `form.btn1Color`, you need to assign a value like this:

```
form1.btn1Color = clr[0, 0];
```

Calling `clr[0, 0] = form1.btn1Color;` only stores the color in the array, nothing else. It does not remember the object itself.

Comment: How can I get it to overwrite the original? My idea was to store the button names in an array so that my array dimensions would match to the relevant button in a 50x50 block of buttons. ie btn17_48.

Comment: You could use `clr` as a struct to store each button and their respective colors.